# How to solve installation errors with VS code server remote?

Tags: visual-studio-code, node.js

Disclaimer: I have no clue of node.js, but I want to install vs code remote development on my ARMv7 NAS. It includes node, but this failed with "Illegal instruction". After a long search I finally got the NAS to compile node from src. And now when I run this new node it gives me kind of a prompt, not an error message. Yippieh so far.

But then I turned back to vs code and its script (server.sh). This just stops after telling me about a few problems. I guess it has to do with this:

```
Error: Module did not self-register: '/root/.vscode-server/bin/fe719cd3e5825bf14e14182fddeb88ee8daf044f/node_modules/spdlog/build/Release/spdlog.node'.
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
[...]
[23:58:40] getUnixShellEnvironment#errorChildProcess A system error occurred (spawn /bin/ash ENOENT)
[23:58:40] ptyHost was unable to resolve shell environment Error: Unable to resolve your shell environment: A system error occurred (spawn /bin/ash ENOENT)
    at /root/.vscode-server/bin/fe719cd3e5825bf14e14182fddeb88ee8daf044f/out/vs/server/remoteExtensionHostAgent.js:85:58666
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async /root/.vscode-server/bin/fe719cd3e5825bf14e14182fddeb88ee8daf044f/out/vs/server/remoteExtensionHostAgent.js:77:22250
[23:58:40] RequestService#request resolving shell environment failed Error: Unable to resolve your shell environment: A system error occurred (spawn /bin/ash ENOENT)
    at /root/.vscode-server/bin/fe719cd3e5825bf14e14182fddeb88ee8daf044f/out/vs/server/remoteExtensionHostAgent.js:85:58666
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async /root/.vscode-server/bin/fe719cd3e5825bf14e14182fddeb88ee8daf044f/out/vs/server/remoteExtensionHostAgent.js:77:22250
```

I am not sure how to proceed here. After these error messages, how would you proceed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get node modules compiled for ARM?](https://superuser.com/questions/1696134/how-can-i-get-node-modules-compiled-for-arm)

Comment: Sorry, but that was my first attempt to post my question and it was rightfully rejected because it included too many questions. Therefore I gave it a new try and split my questions.

Comment: You should edit that question instead of asking new ones. Closed questions can be reopened once the close reason is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Dear all and dear @Daniel B

I have deleted my old post and now I would like to answer my own question. Thanks to a friend I found out that the problem was that vs code server brought some precompiled node modules with it. In this case they were compiled for node version 14. But I had compiled version 16.(something). I did not know that this was a problem. After compiling node.js again from the latest 14.x code the module works now. Wanted to add this here if someone might have the same problems in the future.

Have a great new year!